# How to change the baseline outcome and significance level for MNLogit (statsmodels.api)?

Tags: python, statsmodels

I've been exploring the MNLogit command from the statsmodels.api.  I can't  figure out based on the site documentation how one is to go about changing the baseline regression.  For example, my outcome variables are "Neither", "Cell Only", "Landline", "Both".  It is treating "Both" as the baseline outcome when I want it to be "Neither".

Also, how does one change the command to test at the 5% significance level with a 95% CI?  The default setting seems to be 2.5% and produces a 97.5% confidence interval.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

(1) To set the baseline class, you need to first convert your endogenous variable to categorical type. You then need to manually reorder the labels with the baseline at the end:

```
df['y'] = df['y'].astype('category').cat.set_categories(new_categories = ['Cell Only' ,'Landline', 'Both', 'Neither'])
fit_mnlogit = sm.MNLogit(endog, exog).fit()
```

(2) It is testing at the 5% confidence level (97.5% - 2.5% = 95% = 100% - 5%). Regardless, if you wish to change the from default `alpha = 0.05`, you specify it in the summary:

```
fit_mnlogit.summary(alpha = 0.01)
```